# can only partially access messages published to ZeroMQ queue

Tags: python, queue, zeromq, subscribe

I have a large Python library with various processes exchanging info via queues using ZeroMQ. I'm running these processes on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instances.

Specifically, I have a process `ProcessPub` that runs constantly on `InstanceA` and once a day it produces a burst of 3 sets of messages that get published to 3 distinct queues `Q1`, `Q2`, and `Q3`. I also have two copies of another process `ProcessSub` running on `InstanceA` and another `InstanceB` which subscribes to these 3 queues, processes the incoming messages and dumps results, including the ingested messages, into local files on disk. Here's what I am observing:

1. `ProcessSub`'s running on both `InstanceA` and `InstanceB` get ALL messages from every burst published to `Q1` and `Q2`
2. `ProcessSub` running on `InstanceA` gets all messages from every burst published to `Q3` EXCEPT for the 1st and last message
3. `ProcessSub` running on `InstanceB` gets NONE of the messages published to `Q3`

In other words, `Q1` and `Q2` appear to be perfectly visible on both `InstanceA` and `InstanceB`, while `Q3` appears to be partially visible on the instance where the messages get produced (`InstanceA`) and totally invisible on `InstanceB`.

The way I subscribe to the 3 queues in `ProcessSub` is the same.

How can I figure out why I am having trouble accessing `Q3` messages?

UPDATE: In `ProcessPub`, I have a block of code that prepares messages for `Q3`, then published them to `Q3`, then does the same with `Q2` and `Q1`. As an experiment, I modified by code by putting the block that published to `Q3` after the block that published to `Q2` and before the `Q1` block. After this change, all 3 queues became visible on `InstanceB`. So with every burst of activity, I would get all messages published to all 3 queues. BUT, I found another issue. The `ProcessSub`'s running on `InstanceA` redirect all messages they capture from the `Q`'s to local files on disk. So every time there is a burst, data would be added to these files in chunks. What I noticed was that the first message from each burst from each queue was missing in the local files. I doubt that has to do with any sort of buffering of files on disk, since it was the first message of every burst, not the last one. By the way, on `InstanceB` the first messages were captured fine. So there is still some sort of issue (or issues).

Comment: Smells like something didn't get connected up for Q3 fast enough. Are all three queues being published over the same ømq socket?

Comment: I think separate sockets. By the way, I ran `netstat` on `InstanceB`. For `Q1` and `Q2` I got `tcp ... ESTABLISHED`, for `Q3` I got `tcp ... CLOSE_WAIT`. Does this shine any light on the problem?

Comment: Can I use `netstat` on either instance to get some additional info? What option(s) should I use?

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you say "*I think separate sockets*". I think that may be the cause of your problem. According to the [ZeroMQ documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-socket) you should really only be opening 1 socket per instance of ZMQ, not 1 socket per PUB/SUB queue.

Comment: Does this mean that if I have multiple processes running on a given instances, which sub/pub to different queues, I must have a single socket for all of them?

Comment: No just a single socket per ZMQ instance. Which means a single socket per process in your case.

Comment: Not sure we can do this for multiple PUB queues. We can SUB to a bunch of queues as essentially one input stream, but we can't do it when a single process publishes to multiple queues. This is because we have to distinguish between the different output streams corresponding to the different queues. I don't think we can do it with a single socket. Or am I wrong?